# Add ;; to the top and bottom of each file in a list

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of the locations of each text file that need this done inside `add.txt`

For example inside `add.txt` I have the following

```
/root/QuestDiary/MapQuest_Def/Mon_Umyounkijang.txt
/root/Market_Def/06Inn_SamakwAr-5.txt
```

I need a script to open every text file in that list and add ;; to the top and bottom of each of them. It also must also open files/folders that have capitals, it's listed as `/root/Market_Def/06Inn_SamakwAr-5.txt` in the file but the actual file name is `/root/Market_DEF/06Inn_SamakWar-5.txt`

`06Inn_SamakWar-5.txt` currently looks like

```
%100
+40
+1

[@main]
#IF
checkpkpoint 2

#SAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_0


#ELSESAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_1

[@buy]

#SAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_2

[@sell]

#SAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_3

[Goods]

Jerk 1000 1

[@TalkToQuest]
#CALL [NPCQuest_Def\02Weapon_BichonSung-10.txt] @NPCQuest_Check

[@everythingreward]
#CALL [System\TotalRewardSystem.txt] @TotalRewardSystem
```

It should change to

```
;;
%100
+40
+1

[@main]
#IF
checkpkpoint 2

#SAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_0


#ELSESAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_1

[@buy]

#SAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_2

[@sell]

#SAY
#INCLUDE [..\Convert_Def\Market_Def\01Meet_BichonSung-10.txt] @Convert_01Meet_BichonSung-10_3

[Goods]

Jerk 1000 1

[@TalkToQuest]
#CALL [NPCQuest_Def\02Weapon_BichonSung-10.txt] @NPCQuest_Check

[@everythingreward]
#CALL [System\TotalRewardSystem.txt] @TotalRewardSystem

;;
```

Comment: It's similar but mine is for files in a specific list.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;'
```

It is composed of two `sed` expressions:

- `1i ;;` inserts (`i`) `;;` (newline embedded) before the first line (`1`)
- `$a ;;` appends (`a`) `;;` (newline embedded) after the last line (`$`)

**Example:**

```
$ cat foo.txt
sdas
adas

$ sed -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' foo.txt 
;;
sdas
adas
;;
```

---

As you have all the files in `add.txt`, assuming no filename contains any character of `IFS` (space, tab, newline by default) nor wildcard charcters (`*`, `?`, `[]`), you can do the following to edit the files in place with a `.bak` extension as backup of the original:

```
sed -i.bak -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' -- $(cat add.txt)
```

Without a backup:

```
sed -i -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' $(cat add.txt)
```

When `-i` is used the files are taken separately instead of a single stream so we are good to go. Without `-i`, we need to use the `-s` option to get separated streams for files.

Or read the filenames, separated by newline, and do operation one by one, with backup:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do sed -i.bak -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' -- "$f"; done <add.txt
```

without backup:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do sed -i -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' -- "$f"; done <add.txt
```

Comment: I did sed -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' foo.txt and all my text files where in foo.txt but it done nothing to them.

Comment: You need to include the `-i` option to get sed to work on the files. So `sed -i -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;'` should do it. This is assuming you're using the GNU version of sed (if you're running a Linux OS you're probably using GNU sed, but probably not if you're using osx for example).

Comment: sed -i -e '1i ;;' -e '$a ;;' foo.txt made no changes to the files listed in foo.txt

Comment: Sorry, it did add ;; to the top and bottom of foo.txt but the script needs to do that to the files that are listed inside foo.txt

Comment: @Rarara221 check my edits.

Comment: Thank you very much that done the trick but I have ran into another problem. The files/folders don't exactly match the add.txt. Some files letter case is wrong (check the top of my post)

Comment: Also this doesn't add a empty line after the ;; on the first line

Comment: Not a empty line sorry, just doesn't go down to the next line afterwards. Look at my example, the output currently is ;;%100

Answer (score 0):

With `cat`:

```
cat <( echo ";;" ) /path/to/inputfile <( echo ";;" )
```

If you have a list of files, you can use:

```
while read file; do
   scratchfile=$(mktemp)
   cat <( echo ";;" ) "$file" <( echo ";;" ) > $scratchfile
   mv -f "$scratchfile" "$file"
done < /path/to/file.list
```

If you have a command (e. g. `find`) providing the list, you can use:

```
IFS="\n"
for file in $( /some/command ); do
   scratchfile=$(mktemp)
   cat <( echo ";;" ) "$file" <( echo ";;" ) > $scratchfile
   mv -f "$scratchfile" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That middle command just pasted the changes on screen but did not apply them to each file.

Comment: I will revise to amend the files.  Be aware then that repeated testing will result in a _lot_ of extra semicolons.